# ASP.NET Boilerplate: Get and GetAll is POST instead of GET method

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspnetboilerplate

I'm using the ASP.NET Boilerplate framework to do a small project and I used Swagger UI Integration to check the API within the project. I noticed that the `Get` and `GetAll` are still using POST method while the others are in their respective HTTP verb for example `Create` is POST, `Edit` is UPDATE, etc... I read the documentation and tried what they suggested in this [Documentation]
(https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Dynamic-Web-API#http-verbs)
[image: app_tenant in the API]

**Edit 1:** Code for `UserAppServiceClass`

```
[AbpAuthorize(PermissionNames.Pages_Users)]
public class UserAppService : AsyncCrudAppService<User, UserDto, long, PagedResultRequestDto, CreateUserDto, UpdateUserDto>, IUserAppService
{
    private readonly UserManager _userManager;
    private readonly RoleManager _roleManager;
    private readonly IRepository<Role> _roleRepository;

    public UserAppService(
        IRepository<User, long> repository, 
        UserManager userManager, 
        IRepository<Role> roleRepository, 
        RoleManager roleManager)
        : base(repository)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _roleRepository = roleRepository;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public override async Task<UserDto> Get(EntityDto<long> input)
    {
        var user = await base.Get(input);
        var userRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id);
        user.Roles = userRoles.Select(ur => ur).ToArray();
        return user;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public override async Task<UserDto> Create(CreateUserDto input)
    {
        CheckCreatePermission();

        var user = ObjectMapper.Map<User>(input);

        user.TenantId = AbpSession.TenantId;
        user.Password = new PasswordHasher().HashPassword(input.Password);
        user.IsEmailConfirmed = true;

        //Assign roles
        user.Roles = new Collection<UserRole>();
        foreach (var roleName in input.RoleNames)
        {
            var role = await _roleManager.GetRoleByNameAsync(roleName);
            user.Roles.Add(new UserRole(AbpSession.TenantId, user.Id, role.Id));
        }

        CheckErrors(await _userManager.CreateAsync(user));

        return MapToEntityDto(user);
    }

    [HttpPut]
    public override async Task<UserDto> Update(UpdateUserDto input)
    {
        CheckUpdatePermission();

        var user = await _userManager.GetUserByIdAsync(input.Id);

        MapToEntity(input, user);

        CheckErrors(await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user));

        if (input.RoleNames != null)
        {
            CheckErrors(await _userManager.SetRoles(user, input.RoleNames));
        }

        return await Get(input);
    }

    [HttpDelete]
    public override async Task Delete(EntityDto<long> input)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserByIdAsync(input.Id);
        await _userManager.DeleteAsync(user);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ListResultDto<RoleDto>> GetRoles()
    {
        var roles = await _roleRepository.GetAllListAsync();
        return new ListResultDto<RoleDto>(ObjectMapper.Map<List<RoleDto>>(roles));
    }

    protected override User MapToEntity(CreateUserDto createInput)
    {
        var user = ObjectMapper.Map<User>(createInput);
        return user;
    }

    protected override void MapToEntity(UpdateUserDto input, User user)
    {
        ObjectMapper.Map(input, user);
    }

    protected override IQueryable<User> CreateFilteredQuery(PagedResultRequestDto input)
    {
        return Repository.GetAllIncluding(x => x.Roles);
    }

    protected override async Task<User> GetEntityByIdAsync(long id)
    {
        var user = Repository.GetAllIncluding(x => x.Roles).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        return await Task.FromResult(user);
    }

    protected override IQueryable<User> ApplySorting(IQueryable<User> query, PagedResultRequestDto input)
    {
        return query.OrderBy(r => r.UserName);
    }

    protected virtual void CheckErrors(IdentityResult identityResult)
    {
        identityResult.CheckErrors(LocalizationManager);
    }
}
```

**Edit 2:**

[image: app_user]

Comment: Sorry about that I already edited the question and yes I already added `WithConventionalVerbs` in the Web Api Module

Comment: Is it Asp.Net Core?

Comment: Nope, i'm using Asp.Net MVC

Comment: add your ABP version to the question

Comment: @DaveL Please edit the code to increase readability and keep the methods for which you are facing issues.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Get` method has **complex** `input` argument: `Get(EntityDto<long> input)`. HTTP GET verb can't pass it to server, that is why ASP.NET Boilerplate has no choice, it decide to assign POST verb instead. Only parameters like `/Get?name=Max&age=22` are allowed for GET - at this case method's signature will be like this: `Get(string name, int age)`.

So you should leave all of it without changes or change signature to flattern variant, enumerating properties of `EntityDto<long>` as comma separated arguments.

Comment: It's not correct, I,m using `EntityDto<long>`, `EntityDto<string>` and `EntityDto<int>`. Its `Get` method.

Comment: @viveknuna, very interesting. Can you show us your expanded swagger UI (with arguments description) on one of these methods?

Answer (score 0):

You have to write Http Verb attributes to the interface. Not to the method implementations!

```
public interface IUserAppService: IApplicationService
{
    [HttpGet]
    GetUserOutput Get(GetInput input);

    [HttpGet]
    GetAllOutput GetAll(GetAllInput input);    
}
```

Do it for **IAsyncCrudAppService**

PS: For the methods come from base, you can new them in your interface.